# Grais Rest: get a Json object from a "lastName" and not "id"

Tags: rest, grails

How get a user of this class, from a lastName, not from the id.
in my example i use a REST web service.
My class USER.groovy in Grails:

```
class User {
     String firstName
     String lastName
     String zipcode }
```

class UrlMappings.groovy

```
class UrlMappings {
       static mappings = {

               /user/$id" (controller: "user") {
                            action = [GET: "show"]
               }
       }
}
```

**def show** in UserController.groovy

```
def show = {
   User user = User.get(params.id)
   if (user) {
      render user as JSON
   } else {
      SendNotFoundResponse()
   }

 }
```

Comment: My problem is to retrieve an Json object from other fields that "id"

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, your problem that you don't know how to query domain by other fields that id. For current example you can use:

```
User.findByFirstName(params.id)
```

And, please read about GORM querying - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying

Comment: +1 Just be careful using this solution, User.findBy______() will always return one User. So by building your system like this you would be limiting your system to only have one person with lastName (or whatever field you are searching by). finalAllBy____() will return a list, but then the logic becomes more complicated.

Comment: how can I recover from User two parameter, exmp by firstName and lastName for the exemple ?  and how will be the structure of URL in web navigator ?

Comment: `findByFirstNameAndLastName`, please read link from my answer. And about url mapping - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings